# jquery ajax ie8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, browser-cache

i have a problem with ajax and ie8.
my script:

```
$('#buton').click(function () {
        $('#reader-cont #imgw, #reader-cont #txtw, #reader-cont #datew, #reader-cont #sharemew').html('<div id="ajload"></div>');
        $('#reader').stop().fadeTo(1000, 1).css('z-index', 100);
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            cache:false,
            success: function(data) {
                var imgW = $(data).find("#content #img");
                var txtW = $(data).find(".cont-cont").text();
                var  dateW =   $(data).find("#content #date");
                var  shareW =   $(data).find('#content #shareme')
                $("#reader-cont #imgw").html(imgW);
                $("#reader-cont #txtw").html(txtW);
                $("#reader-cont #datew").html(dateW);
                $("#reader-cont #sharemew").html(shareW);
                alert(txtW);
        }
        });
    });
```

ff and chrome don't have a problem to load a content, but ie8 don't load nothing... why??? i know ie8 have a problem with a cahe, for it i write `cache:false,`,but not load.........

more info:
the `alert(txtW);` return empty string...
if i remove `.text()` from `var txtW = $(data).find(".cont-cont").text();` return in alert windows "Object, Object"...

update: i switch the script with this:

```
loadXMLDoc();
    function loadXMLDoc()
            {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    var data= xmlhttp.responseText;
                    alert(data);
                var imgW = $(data).find("#content #img");
                var txtW = $(data).find(".cont-cont");
                var  dateW =   $(data).find("#content #date");
                var  shareW =   $(data).find('#content #shareme')
                $("#reader-cont #imgw").html(imgW);
                $("#reader-cont #txtw").html(txtW);
                $("#reader-cont #datew").html(dateW);
                $("#reader-cont #sharemew").html(shareW);
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET",link,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
```

the alert in ie8 run perfectly, but in the div i don't see nothing.... the cache is not a problem now... the problem is find the selector in loaded content...

i tested it in ie9 ff chrome safari... work perfectly...
but not in ie8

update 2:
i learn the problem is .find, because the alert return the page for data.
i try in this method, but ie8 don't run :(

i switch this line:

```
var imgW = $(data).find("#content #img");
                var txtW = $(data).find(".cont-cont");
                var  dateW =   $(data).find("#content #date");
                var  shareW =   $(data).find('#content #shareme')
```

with this line:

```
var data= xmlhttp.responseText;
                    var imgW = $(data).children('#wrapper').children('#content').children(' .region').children('#block-system-main').children('.content').children('#img');
                    var txtW = $(data).children('#wrapper').children('#content').children(' .region').children('#block-system-main').children('.content').children(".cont-cont");
                    var  dateW =   $(data).children('#wrapper').children('#content').children(' .region').children('#block-system-main').children('.content').children("#content #date");
                    var  shareW =   $(data).children('#wrapper').children('#content').children(' .region').children('#block-system-main').children('.content').children('#content #shareme');
```

ff chrome no prob ie8 don't run -.-@!#

Comment: What is the link url? internal or cross domain?

Comment: have you consider using jquery.ajax for a get request ? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: i try it in first solution, but nothing go in ff chrome safari but not in ie8... now i think the problem is this line:

var imgW = $(data).find("#content #img");
                var txtW = $(data).find(".cont-cont");
                var  dateW =   $(data).find("#content #date");
                var  shareW =   $(data).find('#content #shareme')
because the alert send me the page, but ie don't find the div i search...

Comment: ok i have alerted al js... the problem is the .find, it's a bug of jquery with ie8... in javascript what i write for run it??

Comment: @cr34 Found any solutions on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In case of your server `IIS` in order to deal with cache issue with `IE8`,
you should do some work on your server code:

From [this link](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/297122-response-expires-response-cache)

Put below code in your `Global.asax`

```
Response.Expires = 0
Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that jQuery is switching to `.done()`, as shown.
Make a free-standing function and then call it from your `$.ajax(...)`

```
var arrayData=[];
$.ajax({
    ...  
}).done(function(data){
    arrayData[0]=$(data).find("#content #img");
    //add other elements
    updCont(arrayData);
});
function updCont(htmArray){
    $("#reader-cont #imgw").html(htmArray[0];
}
```

Also, note that jQuery is switching to .done(), which btw still has the same IE8-doesn't-work problem. I lost **DAYS** to this rotten behavior.